# Can I use QR decomposition as a last step in a Constrained Orthonormal Matrix Optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I have the optimization problem: minimise $f(V)$, where $V$ is $N\times N$, subject to

1. $V$ is orthonormal
2. All entries of the first column of $V$ are $1/\sqrt{N}$
3. $V \cdot D \cdot V^T \cdot \mathbf{1}_N = \mathbf{0}_N$ (I do not optimize over $D$)

Because of (1), I resorted to the `Manopt` package in Matlab where I optimize over a Stiefel Manifold to obtain an Orthonormal Matrix.

But due to (2) and (3), I resorted to the Augmented Lagrangian Method to solve the problem, where I modified my original optimization problem to include (2) and (3).

However, too many iterations are required to nicely obey (2) and (3).

So I am doing some intuitive tricks (with no theoretical justification) after I obtain $V$ via optimizing over the Stiefel manifold:

- Step 1: Solve Augmented Lagrangian Method.
- Step 2: Obtain a $V$.
- Step 3. **Replace** the first column of $V$ with all $1/\sqrt{N}$ to obtain a modified V
- Step 4. **Perform** QR decomposition over this modified $V$, to obtain another Orthonormal $V$.

In steps 3 and 4, I have doubts whether these are the right steps to obey my constraints. The surprising thing is that they seem to work, but seems unethical to me, because:

1. In step 3, I am replacing the first column of the $V$ with all $1/\sqrt{N}$, **now** at this point in time my $V$ **may not be orthonormal** anymore!
2. Then I do a QR decomposition over this modified $V$ which may not be orthonormal. So this QR decomposition doesn't seem to make sense.

Please let me know whether my trick is right or wrong. If correct, please kindly try to give a proof or theoretical justification. If wrong, then please tell me it's wrong. Also in case of any better alternative, please also tell me that.

Comment: What is size(V,1)? Also for constraint 3, do you mean "there exists D such that ... holds"?

Comment: Its basically the dimension of V, i.e. N...sorry i wrote matlab syntax ill edit in question as well

Comment: Is $D$ diagonal? Then $D_{1,1}=0$. Generally the first column of $D$ has to be zero.

Comment: With handwavium: Your $V$ from step 1 is already close to being admissible and minimizing. Replacing the first column with the constant and then replacing $V$ with $Q$ should in both cases not significantly increase the distance. The result is an admissible point that is still close to a minimum.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes the D is indeed diagonal

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes absolutely, this is the same thing I observed before making the replacement and qr orthogonalisation, and I am rather now finding that this actually in a sense is acting like accelerating the Augmented lagrangian as even with far less iterations i achieve that matrix which otherwise classic ALM would take quite longer..